# Ruby on Rails tutorial chapter 8.2.6 Capybara element not found error + no method error undefined method it

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I was working through the tutorial and got this error

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication signin followed by signout 
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
      no link with title, id or text 'Sign out' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have thoroughly researched this question and although there are similar questions, I have tried their solutions but they didn't work.

Here is the relevant code:

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def new
 end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Sessions helper

```
module SessionHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
   !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token)
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end 
end
```

User pages spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

    describe "signup" do

      before { visit signup_path }

      let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

      describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
          expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end
      end

      describe "with valid information" do
        before do
          fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
          fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
          fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
          fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
          expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "after saving the user" do
          before { click_button submit }
          #let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }
          let(:user) { User.where(email: 'user@example.com').first }

          #it { should have_title(user.name) }
          it { should have_selector( "title", :content => user.name)}
          #it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
          it { should have_link('Sign out') }       
        end
      end
   end
 end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Authentication pages spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    #it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    #it { should have_title('Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

 describe "signin" do

   before { visit signin_path }

   describe "with invalid information" do
     before { click_button "Sign in" }

     it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
     it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

     describe "after visiting another page" do
       before { click_link "Home" }
       it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
     end
   end

   describe "with valid information" do
     let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     before do
       fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
       fill_in "Password", with: user.password
       click_button "Sign in"
     end

     #it { should have_title(user.name) }
     it { should have_selector( "title", :content => user.name)}
     it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
     it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
     it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
     end

     describe "followed by signout" do
       before { click_link "Sign out" }
       it { should have_link('Sign in') }
     end
   end
 end
```

Any help and an explanation of what is wrong and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT.

The capybara error is gone but now I have a new error,

Failures:

```
1) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_selector( "title", :content => user.name)}
   NoMethodError:
   undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_1:0xb4063c4>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:42:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the edited version of Authentication pages spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
.
.
.
.
  describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"


    #it { should have_title(user.name) }
    #it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector( "title", :content => user.name)}
    it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
  end

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
   end
  end
 end
end
```

What is wrong here? My syntax is correct and that line wasn't giving an error before so why now? Any help and an explanation why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not signed in. Check the nesting/indentation on that failing `describe` clause and you'll find that you terminated the "with valid information" block prematurely with the `end` immediately following the `it` one-liners.

Comment: hey thanks for the help that fixed the error however when I ran rspec again I got a new error.                               Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector( "title", :content => user.name)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `it' . any help on how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: "it" is only defined within a "describe" block

Comment: The it code which is giving me the error is within a describe block but I still get the error, I am confused, please look at the modified version of authentication pages spec.

Comment: Now the `it` is inside of the `before` block. Your before block was fine before. As I said, the problem previously was the _premature_ termination of the `describe` block. You needed to move that `end` that was just before the last `describe` to after it.

Comment: These problems are less likely to "bite" you if you make sure your indentation is always right.